# Java DXA version on Tridion Sites 10

Tags: dxa-java, sites-10

We are migrating from Tridion Sites 9.5 to Tridion Sites 10.

What version of DXA is adapted to Sites 10?

Comment: what version of DXA you are currently using?

Comment: We are using Version 2.2.3

Comment: I would expect DXA 2.2 to be loosely coupled to CD and therefore to run fine on Tridion Sites 10, even though it is not specifically "adapted to Sites 10".  Are you experiencing problems with running DXA 2.2.3 on Sites 10?